# Axis scale in google charts (from google spreadsheets)

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, google-visualization

I've generated chart form google spreadsheets. In my report for horizontal axis I have values: 1
,2
,3
,4
,5
,10
,20
,30
,40
,50
,100
,200
,300
,400
,500
,600
,700
,800
,900
,1000.
Chart interprets them as a labels, not a number:

[image]

So the distance between 1 and 4 is the same as between 20 and 50. How to change it? (Maybe I have to transform input data - how?)

[Here is my spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets1.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtdHElsKyNw9dERVZ1lZRVNmYmRqSlVVbWszd3BVdGc&hl=en_US#gid=0) with input data, query and the chart.

I want to embed it in a webpage with such script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> 
{"dataSourceUrl":"//spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AtdHElsKyNw9dERVZ1lZRVNmYmRqSlVVbWszd3BVdGc&transpose=0&headers=1&range=F1%3AI21&gid=0&pub=1",
"options":{
    "reverseCategories":false,"titleX":"thousand objects","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","pointSize":0,
    "width":510,
    "vAxis":{"format":"#0.##########"},
    "smoothLine":true,"lineWidth":2,"logScale":false,"hasLabelsColumn":true,
    "hAxis":{"maxAlternation":1},
    "vAxes":[{"min":null,"title":"ms","max":null,"maxValue":null}],
    "title":"Performance of exposing previous value in AspectJ set-pointcut",
    "height":400,"interpolateNulls":false,"legend":"bottom","reverseAxis":false
},
"state":{},
"chartType":"LineChart",
"chartName":"Performance test"
} </script>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by configuring the vertical axis in the Advanced Settings area.

[image]

I just did and it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: are you sure that "Log scale" doesn't mean "Logarithmic scale" ?
Look here: http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63824
"Log scale sets a logarithmic scale to your data"

Comment: Is there possible to make a logarithmic scale on google sheet with exotic log power (like 1 3 9 27 ...)? Or is it fixed?

Answer (score 6):

In Google Spreadsheet, the only chart type that I know understand the axes as numbers is the **Scatter**.

If it does not suit you (e.g. because you want a line specifically), then you have to work the data. That is, you have to determine a fixed step your axes, e.g. 10 (or any other resolution you find necessary) and fill the data columns using some formula based on your data, like a linear regression between the adjacent points, or a polynomial interpolation.

I'm not very skilled in the QUERY function, maybe it can help you do it automagically. I only know how to do it using other "more complicated" formulas structures with ArrayFormulas and so.

Comment: Are there any updates on that answer? Is it possible with the new Google Chart Api to have specific x-values (not only evenly spaced)

Answer (score 6):

I found other solution.
Use type for X axis data as "number" (not as string) and line chart

Check that documentation for details:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you added an explanation on how you did this, linking to the explanation as a source, not as the explanation. Also, that would make this answer be in line with the SE guidelines for how an answer should be written.